# Use property value as key in map statement without intermediate object assignment

Tags: typescript, dictionary, javascript-objects

I have an array objects that look like this:

```json
{
    "id": "id",
    "events": [{
        "status": "DELETED",
        "timestamp": 0,
        "properties": {
            "key": "value"
        }
    }],
    "additionalProperty": "someValue"
}
```

I want to format this array so that the final representation looks like this:

```json
{
    "id": [{
        "status": "DELETED",
        "timestamp": 0
    }]
}
```

Multiple objects would look as follows:

```
{
    "id": [{
        "status": "DELETED",
        "timestamp": 0
    }],
    "id2": [{
        "status": "CREATED",
        "timestamp": 0
    }]
}
```

And I have the following interface in typescript:

```js
interface Response {
    [id: string]: {
        status: string
        timestamp: number
    }[]
}
```

How can I iterate over the objects and format each object to satisfy the interface? I've tried using the map function, but creates an array of objects:

```js
return obj.map(o => ({
    [o.id]: o.events.map(e => {
        delete e.properties
        return e
    })
}))
```

However this gives the error:

> Type '{ [x: string]: { status: string; timestamp: number; }[]; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Response'.
> Index signature is missing in type '{ [x: string]: { status: string; timestamp: number; }[]; }[]'

I have managed to solve it using `forEach` instead, but is it possible to do without the intermediate object?

```js
private formatResponse(packages: PackageDocument[], packageId?: string): PackageHistoryResponse {
    const response: Response = {}
    obj.forEach(o => response[o.id] = o.events.map(e => ({ status: e.status, timestamp: e.timestamp })))
    return response
}
```

**Full reproducible code**

Confirmed running using ts-node.

```js
let someObjects = [{
    id: "id",
    events: [{
        status: "DELETED",
        timestamp: 0,
        properties: {
            key: "value"
        }
    }],
    additionalProperty: "someValue"
}, {
    id: "id2",
    events: [{
        status: "CREATED",
        timestamp: 1,
        properties: {
            key: "value"
        }
    }],
    additionalProperty: "someValue"
}]

interface ResponseInterface {
    [id: string]: {
        status: string
        timestamp: number
    }[]
}

console.log("What I have achieved with a one-line expression")
console.log(JSON.stringify(someObjects.map(o => ({
    [o.id]: o.events.map(e => {
        return { status: e.status, timestamp: e.timestamp }
    })
})), null, ' '))

console.log("What I want (preferably in the same fashion as above)")
console.log(JSON.stringify(formatResponse(someObjects), null, ' '))

function formatResponse(objects: any[]): ResponseInterface {
    const response: ResponseInterface = {}
    objects.forEach(o => response[o.id] = o.events.map((e: { status: any; timestamp: any }) => ({ status: e.status, timestamp: e.timestamp })))
    return response
}
```

Comment: pls share reproducable example

Comment: @captain-yossarian updated, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

My solution. I don't know that is exactly what you want.

```js
interface ResponseInterface {
  [id: string]: {
    status: string;
    timestamp: number;
  }[];
}

let someObjects = [ { id: "id", events: [ { status: "DELETED", timestamp: 0, properties: { key: "value" } } ], additionalProperty: "someValue" }, { id: "id2", events: [ { status: "CREATED", timestamp: 1, properties: { key: "value" } } ], additionalProperty: "someValue" } ];

// you can change any for specified interface
function convertArrToObj(array: any[]): ResponseInterface {
  const results: ResponseInterface = {};

  array.forEach(({ id, events }) => {
    results[id] = [];
    events.forEach(({ status, timestamp }) =>
      results[id].push({ status, timestamp })
    );
  });
  return results;
}

console.log(convertArrToObj(someObjects));
```

The output:

```
{
  "id": [
    {
        "status": "DELETED",
        "timestamp": 0
    }
  ],
  "id2": [
    {
        "status": "CREATED",
        "timestamp": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my goal was no intermediate object and there can be multiple events, so should be an array

Comment: fixed, try this now